Dart Stream Future.delayed incorrect delay
I'm trying to make a Stream modifier function which adds 'latency' to all items going through it:
extension SE<T> on Stream<T> {
  Stream<T> delayed(Duration latency) {
    return this.transform(StreamTransformer<T, T>.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (T element, EventSink<T> sink) {
        Future.delayed(latency).then((_) => sink.add(element));
      }
    ));
  }
}

void main() async {
  final s1 = Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (i) => i);
  final s2 = Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (i) => i).delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  
  s1.forEach((i) => print('$i'));
  s2.forEach((i) => print('  $i'));  
}

From the code above, you would expect it to print alternating increasing integers with 500ms between each line:
0
  0
1
  1
2
  2
...

However this is really not the case, as seen in this dartpad
Does anyone know why this is happening? Perhaps my current understanding of how async and Streams works in Dart isn't enough.
Cheers! Dan

I'm confused about how what you're observing is different from what you expected to observe.  When I run your DartPad code, I do see the output you've shown, and each line is printed ~500ms apart.

You're probably running into unpredictable behavior because you're using the transformer exactly how the documentation says not to. According to the documentation on StreamTransformer.fromHandlers:
"The sink provided to the event handlers must only be used during
the call to that handler. It must not be stored and used at a later
time."
